# iOS Drawing HTML to PDF in multiple columns

Tags: html, ios, pdf

I'm drawing HTML to a PDF using the code below. When the HTML renders to the device I'm using css columns to layout the HTML in two columns, but when it renders to PDF it is only in a single column. Is there a way I can render the HTML in multiple columns as a PDF? I'm guessing `UIPrintPageRenderer` doesn't support columns but can't find anything to confirm that.

The reason I'm using css columns is that the content is of variable length and I want it to overflow to the next column dynamically.

Here's my code. `content` is a `String` that contains HTML. I send the exact same string to `UIWebView.loadHTMLString(_:baseURL:)` and it renders in two columns.

```
    let renderer = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    renderer.headerHeight = 36
    renderer.footerHeight = 36

    let htmlFormatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: content)
    htmlFormatter.startPage = 0
    htmlFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 36, 0, 36)
    renderer.addPrintFormatter(htmlFormatter, startingAtPageAtIndex: 0)

    let paperRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792)
    let printableRect = CGRectInset(paperRect, 0, 0)
    renderer.setValue(NSValue.init(CGRect: paperRect), forKey: "paperRect")
    renderer.setValue(NSValue.init(CGRect: printableRect), forKey: "printableRect")

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, metadata)

    for i in 0 ..< renderer.numberOfPages() {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        renderer.drawPageAtIndex(i, inRect: bounds)
    }
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
```

The CSS for rendering in columns that works for `UIWebView.loadHTMLString(_:baseURL:)` but not for PDF is below. I have the `@media` bit to only show in a single column on smaller screens. However I've tried both removing this and adding an `@media print` section to no avail: it still only prints as a single column for PDF.

```
    .content {
        -webkit-columns: auto 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-columns: auto 2; /* Firefox */
        columns: auto 2;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
        .content {
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-columns: auto 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -moz-columns: auto 1; /* Firefox */
            columns: auto 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can share your source code out of it ? Even if only some of the source code fragment .

Comment: @ylgwhyh I've added my code above.

Comment: Try adding `!important` onto the end of each css column value? Might be possible it's being overridden...

Comment: @hakJav thanks, but that didn't work

Comment: did you fix it? I am with the same problem here, tried a lot of different stuff but nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead of css columns try using the html columns and just style the columns using css. I think the UIGraphics will only grab the HTML structure.

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>YourStuffHere</td>
     <td>YourStuffHere</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: I want the columns to be able to flow depending on the content. Sorry, I should have clarified in the question. I'll edit it now.

Comment: You might have to use javascript to change the columns because javascript have a lot of pdf writers.